# How to perform cryptographic algorithmic performance test on localhost using JMETER

Tags: php, performance, encryption, jmeter, cryptography

How to do performance testing on localhost. I did use PHP

I tried a few things but it didn't work. How do I test the performance of a text encoder like this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're want to test a specific function it's better to consider using a [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) like [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler)

JMeter is a protocol-based performance testing tool which means that it can simulate a [real user using a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) accessing your application

If this is something you're looking for you can record your test scenario using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) and after performing some [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) and see how does response time and the number of requests/errors per second look like when hundreds/thousands of users are concurrently accessing your website.

Regarding "localhost" - I don't think it's the best approach because cryptographic operations are very resource intensive and JMeter can be resource intensive as well, it's better to conduct the load from another machine to get more "clear" results